# Symfony2: calling helper in view

Tags: php, forms, symfony, foreach, helper

I have a problem with a helper in Symfony2. I have a helper which works fine. And I have a view made with PHP and HTMl without sintax errors.

I need to make a foreach and in that foreach, I need to create a button which call my helper which some information of this iteration and If an user click in this button, call this helper with this information.

Some like:

```
foreach $i...

<form action="<?php echo $view['entities']->HelperFunction($i) ?>"  >
                <button type="submit">Helper Call</button>
...
end foreach
```

My problem is that in each iteration, automatically the helper is called and his function executed. I need to execute only the helper when I click in the button generated.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at your pseudo-code, I can't work out why you're using symfony2. I mean: Symfony2 has an excellent form component, which you don't seem to use, and comes with twig templating out of the box. Why would you use a framework, and not use the goodies?

Comment: " If an user click in this button, call this helper with this information." --- This belongs to client-side code (`JS`)?

Comment: This is a good example, how NOT TO USE SYMFONY... please use the form API, you can do everything with it: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use symfony forms for this or if it is something custom and you don't have any field inside the form you just for some reason wants to use a function, you can still use symfony not pure PHP in your controller which render the view pass the variable $view['entities'] to the twig like this :

```
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
     /* your codes */

    return $this->render('yourBundle:Default:yourtwigfile.html.twig', array(
        'view' => $view['entities'],
    ));
```

PS : yourBundle:Default:yourtwigfile.html.twig : Default is the folder by default which is yourBundle/Resources/views, if you have a folder inside views like yourBundle/Resources/views/folder it would be yourBundle:folder:yourtwigfile.html.twig

Then inside the twig file in your  action use this :

```
   {% for i in 0..10 %}

   <form action="{% view.HelperFunction(i) %}"  >
            <button type="submit">Helper Call</button>
   ...
   {%endfor%}
```

i didn't test this but it should work, i don't know why you want to do this but it will generate lot of forms depending on how many time you want the for to run.